# Displaying the actual value with the where method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have this method:

```
def regionlist
Steppy.where(:region => 'Canada').all
end
```

which returns an array to me, however what i need is the actualy value of the region, any help on how to do this?

right now in my view i get this: (disregard the values):

```
[#< Steppy id: 48, goal: "baby", region: "Canada", description: "", step1: "k", step2: "k", step3: "k", step4: "", step5: "", step6: "", step7: "", step8: "", step9: "", step10: "", ask: "", created_at: "2013-12-26 18:27:32", updated_at: "2013-12-26 18:27:32">]
```

Ultimatley, all I need is a list of links, of all those that have the same value for goal, eg all those where goal = baby, to display their values of regions

Comment: If you mean actual object, for the first `region` that matches the where criteria, try: `Steppy.where(:region => 'Canada').first`

Comment: i will update in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have your route defined for `steppy` as follows:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :steppies
```

In your view:

```
<% regionlist().each do |region| %>
  <%= link_to region.region, steppy_path(region) %>
<% end %>
```

Where your `regionlist` helper is:

```
def regionlist
  Steppy.where(:goal => 'baby')
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, where do i put def regionlist? in the steppies helper or do i make a new one?

Comment: i tried din the application helper and steppies helper but i do not get anything

Comment: @user2472480, apologies.  Missed to add `each` for `regionlist()` in the view.  Please see updated answer.

Comment: thank you soo much!!! really, now if the goal changes from page to page, would you recommend i use a variable? or is there a better way to say, use current goal?

Comment: to clear up: i dont know that the value of the goal is 'baby', rather a user visits a page where a goal value is already set,

Comment: Would it be feasible to pass it in URL parameters?  Or are you thinking some sort of session state?

Comment: the goal is displayed on the page, its part of a resource, ill try to explain in detail, users fill out a form of how to achieve a certain goal, once they visit a page for a certain goal, i want the list fo the same goal but in different regions displayed by the region name, which already works, so just gotta set the goal to be equal to whatever the goal that is being currently viewed, in urls they show up as /steppies/(id of a steppy)

Comment: because i cant do somethign like Steppy.where(:goal => :goal), Steppy.where(:goal => current_goal)

Comment: hey figured it out! jsut had to do this: Steppy.where(:goal => @steppy.goal), thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) answer your question?